# set two picture and dragg pictures at the same time in a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need to do something like this one picture.where if i drag it any map other map will automatically dragging.and that downtown map should be inside that mobile frame. And this two map images are in different divider  [image]

Comment: So detect the offset and apply it to the other one.

Comment: please formulate better your question. show an html example

Comment: how to use offset and drag both at the same time ?

Comment: i want that two simultaneously moving like this page  http://urban-walks.com/#map

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it working on different types of maps, but you can easly do it with google maps. You can just link one div to another and pass vanishing point. Size of the map is included in link to google map, so that will be easy to change ;)

Comment: i called it map because its a map images :) i want exactly like this page  http://urban-walks.com/#map .pls help me\

Comment: then you can make anchor on center of both pictures and move both bu the vectors. You wil must remember to multiply "down vector" by difference between size of images ;)

Comment: can you give me a short code example ? it will be really good for me to understand. i am not that much familiar with it .

Comment: don't have a time, becouse i am in the work right now. Google the anchor, and try to do it on your own ;) this will make you better programmer (looking for your own ideas, not copying them or basic on them)

Comment: yea  obviously.... actually i am also running out of time :D its ok dude thanks for your info ... :) i am trying to do it :P no other choice :)